# Agregar valores de otro arreglo , python

Tags: python

Tengo dos consultas sql, las cuales almaceno en dos arreglos cada uno; mi primer arreglo contiene 23 posiciones y el segundo 17, pero quiero traerme solo ciertas posiciones del segundo al primero.

Lo que se me ocurre es recorrer el primer arreglo (PuntoDeCorte) y buscar el valor de la posicion [0] en el segundo arreglo (Validaciones) y llamar las posiciones que quiero.

Este es mi codigo, lo que he intentado.

```
def Base_adherencia():
    apro = PuntoDeCorte()
    val = Validaciones()

    base = []

## CREANDO ARREGLO BASE    
    for row in apro:
        base.append(row)
        
## AGREGANDO VALIDACIONES AL ARREGLO BASE
    print("AGREGANDO VALIDACIONES AL ARREGLO BASE")
    for row in val:
        a = base[0]
        b = val [0]
        if a == b:
            base.append(val[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17])

    for row in base:
        print(row)
```

Algo así sería lo esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías mostrar un ejemplo de los dos arrays y cual es la salida esperada? no se entiende bien que querés hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creé las funciones de ejemplo

```
def PuntoDeCorte():
    return  [2000, 170, 247, 133, 'B11', 576, 'a', 35, 124]

def Validaciones():
    return [2000,111,'a',31415,1.2475]
```

En python 3.6 para adelante, podés concatenar listas con '+'

```
def Base_adherencia():
    apro = PuntoDeCorte()
    val = Validaciones()

    if apro[0]==val[0]:
        base = apro+val[1:]
    else: #no tienen el mismo código
        base =[]
    print(base)
```

por otro lado, comentar que podés indexar arrays en python utilizando `:` por ejemplo: `a[:]` es todo el array (lo mismo que escribir `a`) pero por ejemplo podrías decir todo el array partiendo del segundo elemento `a[1:]` y la notación general es `a[start:end:step]` donde `start` es el índice de comienzo del array (los arrays de python empiezan en 0) `end` el último valor y `step` es el salto o paso.

También se puede indexar "negativamente" por ejemplo `a[-1]` es el último elemento, `a[-2]` el anteúltimo y así (y se pueden usar los índices negativos para los recortes con `:`)

Comment: Solo quiero aclarar algo. a[:] NO es lo mismo que a. En caso de las listas, a[:] crea una copia superficial de a. Es más bien equivalente a a.copy().

Answer (score 0):

**Espero que te sirva el código**

Se realiza las listas que se usaran para integrarle valores.

```
#Se crean dos listas
PuntoDeCorte = []
Validaciones = []
```

Luego creamos nuestra función en conjunto de dos argumentos.

```
#Se crea la función base, junto con dos argumentos
def base(a,b):
```

Seguidamente realizamos 2 bucles For para poder recorrer y añadirles valores a las listas y lo aumentamos +1, ya que el for quita 1 numero de mas Ej: si se hace de 1 al 10 te llamara un 9 en ves del 10, y empezamos desde el 0.

```
    #Se hacen dos bucles para recorrer y dar valor a las listas aumentado +1
    for i in range(0,a + 1):
        #Usamos los metodos .append para agregar a la lista
        PuntoDeCorte.append(i)
    for e in range(0,b + 1):
        #Usamos los metodos .append para agregar a la lista
        Validaciones.append(e)
```

Finalmente realizamos los print (mostrar en consola).

```
    print("--- Dos lista en una ---")
    print(Validaciones)
```

Concatenamos (juntamos) 2 listas para ser 1 con el método .extend(), también es posible concatenas listas con "+" Ej: lista = lista1 + lista2.

```
    #Concatenamos listas dobles
    PuntoDeCorte.extend(Validaciones)
```

En este punto realizaremos en mostrar en consola los string y 1 método .index(2), se usa para buscar la posición exacto de un numero.

```
    #El método .index() devuelve la posición en la primera aparición del valor especificado.
    print("Buscar el numero dentro de la lista", "---" ,Validaciones.index(2), "---")
```

Para Finalizar declaramos la función y llamamos los valores de los argumentos de la función, en este caso 10 y 20, no poner ni uno mas y ni uno menos ya que saldrá error.

```
base(10,20)
```

Comment: Una respuesta que es tan solo código no suele ser bien recibida. Te recomiendo editarla y explicar un poco lo que hace el código.

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer]. ¡[es.so] no es un repositorio de código! Debes explicar cómo funciona el mismo.

Comment: Ya fue modificado, Gracias